# What is the difference between baseline and benchmark in terms of machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, model, model-evaluation

While reading machine learning related papers, I came across these two terms: baseline and benchmark. Although I thought them to be the same thing, there seem to be some differences between them as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346788/difference-between-baseline-and-benchmark-in-performance-of-an-application#:%7E:text=Basically%3A,relative%20performance%20of%20an%20application.). However, I am still confused in terms of machine learning models, which model to call benchmark and which one to call baseline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A baseline is usually a lower complexity model. New research leads tend to compare against them to justify increased complexity and other requirements.
Often, a random baseline is used, based on either random performance from resampling or a theoretical random performance. This is usually done in applications, not in development of new methods.

A benchmark is a comparison of different competitors. In development, it's often not enough to beat the baseline, the model must be competitive facing other similarly complex models.